# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x \sin^2x$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation Solve $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x \sin^2x$$

i used the substitution $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=t$ we get

$$\frac{dt}{dx}+t=x\sin^2x$$ which is linear first order, using integrating factor method we get the solution

$$te^x=\int xe^x\sin^2xdx+C$$

$$te^x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\int xe^xdx-\int xe^x\cos 2xdx\right)+C=\frac{1}{2}\left(P-Q\right)+C \tag{1}$$

we have $$P=\int xe^x=(x-1)e^x+C'$$

now using integration by parts we have

$$Q=\int xe^x \cos2xdx=x\int e^x\cos 2xdx-\int \left(\int e^x\cos 2xdx\right)dx$$

$$\int xe^x \cos2xdx=\frac{xe^x}{5}\left(\cos 2x+2\sin 2x\right)-\frac{1}{5}\int e^x(\cos 2x+2\sin 2x)dx $$

$$\int xe^x \cos2xdx=\frac{xe^x}{5}\left(\cos 2x+2\sin 2x\right)-\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{e^x}{5}(\cos 2x+2\sin 2x)\right)-\left(\frac{2e^x}{5}(\sin 2x-2 \cos 2x)\right)$$

finally we need to solve another linear differential equation viz:

$$e^x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(P-Q\right)+C$$

which is very tedious.

is  there a good approach?

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt2.pdf

Comment: Look up Method of Variation of Parameters and Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If you are as lazy as I am, considering $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\frac{x}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$$ assume
$$y_p=a+b x+c\sin(2x)+d\cos(2x)+e x\sin(2x)+f x\cos(2x)$$ Replace and identify $a,b,c,d,e,f$. This should be simple.

Comment: Solving for those coefficients can be a nightmare to be fair :-)  this is what CAS are for?

Comment: @DavidG. It took me five minutes with pen and paper.

Comment: So roughly the same time as the original post.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: lazyness can be a virtue. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Write the differential equation as  $$(D^2+2D+1)y=x\sin^2(x)=\frac{x}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$$ then a complete solution can be written as $$y=y_r+y_p$$ where $y_r$ is the **most general solution** of the **reduced equation** $(D^2+2D+1)y=(D+1)^2y=0$ i.e. $y_r=ae^{-x}+bxe^{-x}$ , where $a,b$ are two arbitrary constants.

And $y_p$ is a one **particular integral** given by $$y_p=\frac{1}{(D^2+2D+1)}\frac{x}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$$ i.e. $2y_p=(D+1)^{-2}(x)-(D+1)^{-2}(x\cos(2x))$. Now $$(1+D)^{-2}(x)=\{1+\frac{(-2)}{1!}D+\frac{(-2)(-2-1)}{2!}+....\}=(1-2D)x=x-2.$$ Since $D^2x=0,D^3x=0,....$

Next $(1+D)^{-2}(x\cos(2x))=Re((1+D)^{-2}(xe^{\iota 2x}))$. So that $$(1+D)^{-2}(xe^{\iota 2x})=e^{\iota 2x}\frac{1}{1+2(D+2\iota)+(D+2\iota)^2} x.$$ Again expanding as bi-nomial series as in pervious part and then considering real part you can find particular integral $y_p$.

Comment: During my undergrad, I recall this being termed the ‘Linear D operator’ - is that correct? Also, do you know of any good textbooks on it?

Comment: You are right. Here $D$ stands for $\frac {d}{dx}$, $D^2$ stands for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.Schaum's Outline of Differential Equations-Frank Ayres-McGraw-Hill International Book.

Comment: Thanks so much. Appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous part is classical, though the characteristic polynomial has a double root, giving terms $e^{-x}$ and $xe^{-x}$.

The non-homogeneous one is a little harder, though you are lucky that there is no overlap with the roots. Let us try a solution of the form $y=xz+w$. The equation turns to

$$(z''+2z'+z)x+2z'+z+w''+2w'+w=x\frac{1-\cos 2x}2=x\frac{1-\Re(e^{i2x)}}2.$$

The constant term is dealt with by $\dfrac12$, while the other can be handled using complex numbers, giving

$$z=-\frac12\Re\left(\frac{e^{i2x}}{4+2i+1}\right).$$

Next,

$$w''+2w'+w=\frac12\Re\left(\frac{(i4+1))e^{i2x}}{4+2i+1}\right)$$ and

$$w=\frac12\Re\left(\frac{(i4+1))e^{i2x}}{(4+2i+1)^2}\right).$$